# How to click on copytoclipboard

Tags: java, selenium

How do I click this element

```
< a id="copyclipboard" onclick="return false;" href="#">Copy to clipboard < /a >
```

with selenium web driver and java script?

I tried `driver.findElement(By.id("copyclipboard")).click()` and if I check `clipbrd.exe` file then nothing is copied.

Please let me know how do I solve that problem?

Comment: The script in this link does nothing, it just returns false. How should that change the contents of the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is copied because it has nothing to do the script returns `false`.